# iOS Verify previous app purchase/install

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Is there a way to verify with the apple servers when a user first installed an app?
Let's say you have a payed app and want to make it free with ads but not send ads to those who previously bought.

Since it's not an IAP i assume Store Kit is out of the question.

Later edit: My problem being the ones that buy, delete and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't do that! The best way is to remove your current app from the App Store and relaunch using a different Bundle ID. People who bought it previously can keep it how it is, although they won't get any updates.

**A possible workaround**

Here's a workaround I just thought of. When you send out your next update, set a flag in `NSUserDefaults` to mark everyone who has it now as paid user. That would be for your next update only; you would remove that code right after the update. Then, when you send out your version with ads, check that flag to determine if you should display them. The only problem is that if a paid user ever re-installed the app, they would see ads from then on.

Comment: Yeah,i thought so.P.S. There is no need for 2 app submissions..i can simply send out version with ads witch writes something to a save file and check and write value at app startup..from that point(in future updates,etc) i can assume that anyone that hasn't got the save file/what ever is a user that updated from older(paied) versions.

I'll leave this open a couple of hours and delete it if no one has a better ideea.

Thanks for showing interest :)

Comment: Yes, I think we are on the same page. `NSUserDefaults` is just a shortcut to doing file I/O.

Comment: @woz Are you the *real* woz?